# count the frequency of float64 or int64 with not equal(!=)

Tags: python, pandas

I know there are tons of posts, but it doesn't solve my problem.

i've data frame is this:

```
df1 = [{"Customer Number": "AFIMBN01000BCA17030001177", "Account Name": "Sunarto","Debit/Credit Indicator" : "k","Money" : 100},
    {"Customer Number": "AFIMBN01000BCA17030001177", "Account Name": "Sunarto","Debit/Credit Indicator": "k","Money" : 200},
    {"Customer Number": "AFIMBN01000BCA17030001177", "Account Name": "Sunarto","Debit/Credit Indicator" : "D", "Money" : 0}]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df1

Account Name    Customer Number           Debit/Credit Indicator         Money
Sunarto      AFIMBN01000BCA17030001177       k                            100
Sunarto      AFIMBN01000BCA17030001177       k                            200
Sunarto      AFIMBN01000BCA17030001177       D                             0

Account Name              object
Customer Number           object
Debit/Credit Indicator    object
Money                      int64 (or let's say float64)
```

i want to count frequency based on "Money"

**if** the Money is 0, it won't count.

i've tried with `df1["Money"].value_counts()` doesnt work

```
df1.loc[df1["Money"] != 0, "Per item"] = df1["Money"].value_counts()
df1

Account Name    Customer Number           Debit/Credit Indicator         Money   Per item
Sunarto      AFIMBN01000BCA17030001177       k                            100     1
Sunarto      AFIMBN01000BCA17030001177       k                            200    NaN
Sunarto      AFIMBN01000BCA17030001177       D                             0   NaN
```

but my expectation is

```
Account Name    Customer Number           Debit/Credit Indicator         Money   Per item
Sunarto      AFIMBN01000BCA17030001177       k                            100     1
Sunarto      AFIMBN01000BCA17030001177       k                            200    1
Sunarto      AFIMBN01000BCA17030001177       D                             0   0
```

so my expectation when i apply in pivot, i can get the item which has a value on "Money"

**my expected**

```
gdf = pd.pivot_table(df1, index = ["Account Name","Customer Number"],values = ["Money", "Per item"],aggfunc = np.sum)

gdf.head()

                                                Money              Per item
Account Name      Customer Number
Sunarto           AFIMBN01000BCA17030001177     300                2.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need assign `1` per condition:

```
df1.loc[df1["Money"] != 0, "Per item"] = 1
```

Or convert boolean mask to integers:

```
df1["Per item"] = (df1["Money"] != 0).astype(int)
```

Another solution without `pivot_table` with aggregation:

```
gdf = (df1.groupby(["Account Name","Customer Number"])['Money']
          .agg([('Money','sum'), ('Per item', lambda x: x.ne(0).sum())]))
print (gdf)
                                        Money  Per item
Account Name Customer Number                           
Sunarto      AFIMBN01000BCA17030001177    300         2
```

EDIT:

> may i know why my code doesn't work?

Problem is [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) return Series with counter values, but index values are created by values of original `Series`, here `100, 200`. So indices not match and get missing values. Solution is use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df1.loc[df1["Money"] != 0, "Per item"] = df1["Money"].map(df1["Money"].value_counts())
print (df1)
  Account Name            Customer Number Debit/Credit Indicator  Money  \
0      Sunarto  AFIMBN01000BCA17030001177                      k    100   
1      Sunarto  AFIMBN01000BCA17030001177                      k    200   
2      Sunarto  AFIMBN01000BCA17030001177                      D      0   

   Per item  
0       1.0  
1       1.0  
2       NaN
```

But here is problem if multiple duplicted values, then is not assign `1` but counter values and get wrong output, here double `200` values incorrectly return `4` values instead `2`:

```
df1 = [{"Customer Number": "AFIMBN01000BCA17030001177", "Account Name": "Sunarto","Debit/Credit Indicator" : "k","Money" : 200},
    {"Customer Number": "AFIMBN01000BCA17030001177", "Account Name": "Sunarto","Debit/Credit Indicator": "k","Money" : 200},
    {"Customer Number": "AFIMBN01000BCA17030001177", "Account Name": "Sunarto","Debit/Credit Indicator" : "D", "Money" : 0}]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)


df1.loc[df1["Money"] != 0, "Per item"] = df1["Money"].map(df1["Money"].value_counts())
print (df1)
  Account Name            Customer Number Debit/Credit Indicator  Money  \
0      Sunarto  AFIMBN01000BCA17030001177                      k    200   
1      Sunarto  AFIMBN01000BCA17030001177                      k    200   
2      Sunarto  AFIMBN01000BCA17030001177                      D      0   

   Per item  
0       2.0  
1       2.0  
2       NaN  

gdf = pd.pivot_table(df1, index = ["Account Name","Customer Number"],values = ["Money", "Per item"],aggfunc = np.sum)

print (gdf)
                                        Money  Per item
Account Name Customer Number                           
Sunarto      AFIMBN01000BCA17030001177    400       4.0
```

Comment: omgg thanks for your solve, stupid me hehe...may i know why is my code doesn't work?

Comment: sir.. What is the meaning of "lambda x: x.ne(0).sum()"?  i dont know the function about this statements for

Comment: @charismabathara - Sure, I explain. First `ne` is [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) - it working here same like `!=` and `sum` is for count only `True` values, because `.ne(0)` return `True` and `False` values.